# Python Beautifulsoup. Parse <p></p>

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am learning how to parse with Beautifulsoup. Could someone explain me how to parse `<p></p>` element in `div class="article-content"`. I want to see only content information after script launch. Let me demonstrate what I want:

[image]

I can parse `div class="article-content"` but cant needed info in `<p></p>`. My code looks in such way:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.engadget.com/2014/10/17/local-multiplayer-is-coming-to-android-games/')
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
print parsed_html.body.find('div', attrs={'class':'article-content'}).text
```

But I get also a lot of junk:

```
$ python engadget_parser.py


Ever wish that you could just whip out your Android device and harass a passer-by to play games with you? It's the sort of thing that Nintendo DS users, for example, have been using thanks to that company's StreetPass feature, but, until now, hasn't been available on Google's smartphones. Now, however, the company has an added an update to its games infrastructure that enables "ambient, real-time" games with more than one user - so long that the game relies upon Google's home-grown multiplayer backend. Still, maybe don't sprint into the street and start challenging people to a dual, because they might get the wrong idea.





        onBreak({
            0: function(){
                (function() {
                        var a = {
                                mobilePlacementID: "348-14-15-135b",
                        width: "320",
                        height: "115"
                        };
                    madserver.requestAd(a);
                })();
            },
            768: function(){}
        });






Source: Android Developers (G+)



Tags: android, AndroidGames, gaming, google, googleplaygames, mobile, mobilepostcross





 Hide Comments
0Comments










            _when_.eng("eng.livefyre.init", {
                articleId: 20979699 ,
                domain: "engadget.fyre.co" ,
                siteId: "296092" ,
                el: "livefyre_20979699",
                initialNumVisible: 2
            })



_when_.eng("eng.perm.init");



lab.scriptBs('gravity.js')




onBreak({
    0: function(){},
    320: function(){},
    768: function(){}
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the select method of beautifulsoup in this case. Replace This:

```
print parsed_html.body.find('div', attrs={'class':'article-content'}).text
```

With this:

```
for p in parsed_html.select('div.article-content p'):
    print p.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is very bad code but anyway I will show him, dont poke me, I am just beginner in Python:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url  = "http://www.engadget.com/2014/10/17/castar-augmented-reality/"

html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)


def news_parser(url):
    list = []
    for p in parsed_html.select('div.article-content p'):
        list.append(p.text)
    return list


def longest_text_position(list):
    # sometimes article is not in list[1] position, so I am searching a longest element in list
    a = 0
    longest_text = ""

    for item in list:
        x = len(item)
        if x > a:
            a = x
            longest_text = item

    position = list.index(longest_text)  
    return position


def print_news(position):
    print "-" * 80
    print parsed_html.title.string
    print "-" * 80
    print list[position]
    print "-" * 80
    print " "

list = news_parser(url)
position = longest_text_position(list)
print_news(position)
```

And it is result:

```
$ python engadget_parser_new.py 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
castAR bets big on its augmented reality hardware with move to Silicon Valley
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
And they certainly were. From just a brief hands-on with the new hardware, I could tell the  make out ....ating that I could look around objects by just walking around the table. Henkel-Wallace mentioned a potential for a holodeck application by blanketing a room with that retroreflective material, and I could certainly see a use case for that.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thank you, @Vincent Beltman.